# Styling the Submit Button in a Form

Tags: html, css

I have made a simple form, but I cannot get the submit button to take in its own styles. 
Please tell me why I cannot style the submit button individually, and preferably, how I can target this button only.

```
label{float:left;text-align:right;} 

input{width:44%;} 

textarea{width:99%;float:none;height:300px;} 

input{float:left;padding:20px;margin-bottom:20px;} 

textarea, input{border-radius:5px;border:thin groove #000;} 

textarea:focus, input:focus { 
    outline:none; 
    border: 1px solid #f00; 
    /* create a BIG glow */ 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px #f00; 
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px #f00; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px #f00; 
    border-radius:5px; 
}​ 

#thesubmit{padding:23px;background:#939;font-size:30px;border-radius:20px;} 

<form id="contact_form"> 
    <div> 
        <label for="name"></label> 
        <input type="text" name="Name" value="Enter Name" style="margin-right:20px;"/> 
    </div> 

    <div> 
        <label for="email"></label> 
        <input type="text" name="Email" value="Enter Email"/> 
    </div> 

    <div> 
        <label for="message"></label> 
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Enter Message" id="message" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea> 
    </div> 

    <div class="button"> 
        <input type="submit" value="send now" id="thesubmit" />
```

Comment: After improving the format of your code, it appears that you have not closed the final div or form tag. Was that just an incomplete version of your code? Also is the CSS in a css file? You need to indicate whether it is or not. If it isnt your css wont do what you think because it is not in style tags.

Comment: R.I.P English grammar!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
.button input[type=submit]{ 
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/TvEX3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use id targeted css -

```
#thesubmit {
    /*css for the item with this id only, in this case the button */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your CSS into "style" tags and it will work! Copied your code and the submit button has it's own background color!